# Работает ли в битриксе SubQuery применительно к GetList разделов?

Tags: битрикс

Или только для компонентов?
То есть, можно ли использовать `CIBlockElement::SubQuery` в `CIBlockSection::GetList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Обратите внимание, что CIBlockSection::GetList возвращает CIBlockResult, а SubQuery работает уже на CIBlockElement.